# Some paths of cgroup of a docker container are missing

Tags: docker, contain, cgroups, cadvisor

I use cadvisor to get CPU usage of my docker container, but it's always very small(about 0.001), which should be wrong because it's a production worker container and it should be more than 10% from htop outside the docker.
[image]
And there's no processes in the container. But it has four processes

[image]

I found the cgroup of the container is strange like:

```
$ cat /proc/14996/cgroup
10:pids:/docker/4d7976bc5814e85cc793cc4926c09c150a0e8bb453b8bc01856e8ac0ef17a34a
9:perf_event:/docker/4d7976bc5814e85cc793cc4926c09c150a0e8bb453b8bc01856e8ac0ef17a34a
8:net_cls,net_prio:/docker/4d7976bc5814e85cc793cc4926c09c150a0e8bb453b8bc01856e8ac0ef17a34a
7:freezer:/docker/4d7976bc5814e85cc793cc4926c09c150a0e8bb453b8bc01856e8ac0ef17a34a
6:devices:/
5:memory:/
4:blkio:/
3:cpu,cpuacct:/
2:cpuset:/docker/4d7976bc5814e85cc793cc4926c09c150a0e8bb453b8bc01856e8ac0ef17a34a
1:name=systemd:/system.slice/docker.service/docker/4d7976bc5814e85cc793cc4926c09c150a0e8bb453b8bc01856e8ac0ef17a34a
```

I have no idea what to do for this problem, but I can provide more information if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are super in checking stats for the right container. What OS we are talking about? In the docs they explain some extra configurations required for RHEL for example.

> https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/running.md

Have you specified any concrete run options? Like `--cpu-period=100000 --cpu-q --cpuset-cpus 2 ...`?

You can cross check your status with the `docker stats` command.

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT      MEM %               NET I/O               BLOCK I/O           PIDS
e21c0d937cb9        0.12%               8.27 MiB / 7.624 GiB   0.11%               4.386 kB / 2.192 kB   7.593 MB / 0 B      2
```

Here I have `0.12%` which means it's about one tenth of a percent.
In cAdvisor that would be `0.0012`.

If those don't match it might indicate an issue.